# How to add description to a google drive file in python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I want to upload a file to google drive and add a string to its description.

This is the code so far:

```
def upload_file(filename, filepath, mimetype):
    file_metadata = {'name': filename}
    media = MediaFileUpload(filepath, mimetype=mimetype)
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    print('File ID: %s' % file.get('id'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add the description of file when the file is uploaded. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From :

```
file_metadata = {'name': filename}
```

#### To :

```
file_metadata = {
    'name': filename,
    'description': 'sample description'
}
```

#### Reference :

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify my answer.